# JavaScript Object Property Instantiation

Tags: javascript

If you have an object where the properties are created by calling a function or a constructor, is the order of execution of these guaranteed?

Example:

```js
const testObject = {
  foo: new Date().valueOf(),
  bar: new Date().valueOf()
};

console.log(testObject.foo > testObject.bar);
```

Is it ever possible that foo will be greater than bar?

Comment: Given that later entries for the same key override earlier ones consistently, I think you can assume they're evaluated as written.

Comment: i dont think anything is guaranteed.

Comment: @DanielA.White I think we can interpret this as "specified by the language"

Answer (score 1):

You can try it for yourself. In the latest firefox and chrome it appears to be evaluated as written:

```js
let i = 0;
const counter = () => i++;

const testObj = {
    a: counter(),
    b: counter(),
    c: counter(),
    d: counter(),
    e: counter()
}

console.log(testObj)
```

Comment: This won't tell you if it's specified by the language or just a Firefox/Chrome implementation feature.